# Mac Terminal Permission Denied in my home folder after I changed hostname

Tags: macos, terminal, hostname

Before this, I find my shell prefix is

```
user@promote ~ $
```

here `promote` is my host name, and I changed it by

```
sudo scutil --set Hostname desktop
```

Now my shell prefix is

```
user@desktop ~ $
```

however, after I changed hostname, I couldn't create any folder or do any change in my home folder(`~`)

Comment: could you please run `ls -l -d /Users/<username>` as root and post the output?  Note: I've changed my hostname on Mac OS X, but I have _never_ had what you're describing happen to me afterwards.

Comment: `[dj@djbook ~]$ ls -l -d /Users/dj`

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x+ 29 root  staff  986 Mar 30 13:26 /Users/dj`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow, ownership of your home directory (and possibly some/all of its contents) got assigned to the root account, rather than your user account. This is not a result of changing your computer's hostname. Something else happened around the same time to cause this, but I can't tell what from your description.

There are a couple of ways to fix this; you can do it from Terminal with:

```
sudo chown -R dj /Users/dj
```

(I'm assuming "dj" is your account name; if not, change that parameter to your actual account name.) The other option is to use the "Reset home folder permissions and ACLs" feature in Recovery mode (instructions [here](http://pondini.org/OSX/Password.html)).

Depending on what caused the problem, there might be other damage as well. You might need to use Disk Utility's repair permissions feature to fix system files as well, and/or reset other users' homes the same way as yours.